# Modify ByteArrayOutputStream .write value later in Java

Tags: java

Is there any way to change the value of ByteArrayOutputStream .write later on in the code? (Please note the comment in the code below)

Something similar like:

```
public class test {
    public static int val;
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream outgoingStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        outgoingStream.write(1);
        outgoingStream.write(92);
        val = 23;
        outgoingStream.write(val);
        outgoingStream.write(34);
        val = 69;


        byte[] bytes = outgoingStream.toByteArray();

        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

        for(int i = 0; i<bytes .length;i++) {
            //Outputs 1 92 23 34 but I need it as 1 92 69 34
            System.out.println(in.read());
        }   
    }

}
```

Comment: Short answer: No

Comment: What is the ***real-life*** issue behind this? I believe there should be something to do but you're maybe going the wrong way by trying to change the value directly from the stream

Comment: learn a little more on hacking

Comment: @YassinHajaj lmao, he is probably trying to do something malicious

Comment: You mean you want to write val as a reference and that it changes after you set it to another value? That's not how streams/references work... You need to decide before write what value to write... the stream must be able to send bytes over the internet or save them in a file... so, no take backs... :)

Comment: The reason I am doing this is because I am trying to create an RADIUS packet, where index 4 of it must contain the length of the whole packet. The packet must have other attribute added to it after index 4. So I have no idea how to calculate the final length of that packet and write it at index 4.

Answer (score -2):

You should use another version of write method and address start point of written bytes and then replace:

```
public void write(byte []b, int of, int len)
Writes len number of bytes starting from offset off to the stream.
```

Comment: That doesn't allow going back and modifying a byte already written to the output stream. It just writes a subset of the bytes in `b`.